# How to make adaptive centered div?

Tags: css, sass

What I have now:

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
flex-direction: column;
```

[image]

How it looks with error:
[image]

What's the target:

[image]

I can do it with
`margin-left: *X*px`, but it is not the way I want to solve it.
May I do it with some `flex` properties ?
It is important to do it **without** bootstrap and grid.

Comment: I think you can use position for it.

Comment: Can you show us the relevant HTML because it looks like it's the structure of that that is causing a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a possible solution: Center the box with flexbox and display the errors with `position: absolute;`. You need to take care of responsive optimization if you want to use it on a wider range of devices.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.box {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 400px;
}

.field {
    position: relative;
}

.input {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}

.error {
    position: absolute;
    left: 105%;
    top: 0;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="box">
      <div class="field">
          <input class="input" type="text">
          <div class="error">error 1</div>
      </div>
  
      <div class="field">
          <input class="input" type="text">
          <div class="error">error 2</div>
      </div>
  
      <button>Send</button>
  </div>
  
</div>
```